# Como inserir um dictionary como um array no mongo usando c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Estou montando um sistema de monitoramento, eu tenho uma classe processo que recebe uma string `NomeDoProcesso`, e um `Dictionary<string,Float>Variavel`, no qual o usuário entra com o nome da variável em uma `textBox`, e uma função calcula o Float.

Processo é um array dentro de um documento do Mongo e Variável seria um array dentro de Processo. Seguindo alguns exemplos de código estou fazendo como no código abaixo, mas não esta salvando no banco.

```cs
///Classe que contém meus objetos
public class Processo
    {
        public string NomeProcesso;
        public Dictionary<string, float> Variaveis;
        public int QtdProcessadores;


        public Processo()
        {
            Variaveis = new Dictionary<string, float>();
        }

        public void Monitorar()
        {
            if (Variaveis != null && Variaveis.Count > 0)
            {
                QtdProcessadores = Environment.ProcessorCount;
                foreach (string variavel in Variaveis.Keys)
                {
                    PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Process", variavel, NomeProcesso, true);
                    pc.NextValue(); // Sempre primeiro valor é zero.
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Variaveis[variavel] = pc.NextValue();
                }
            }
```

```cs
///Função para inserir dinamicamente as variáveis, preciso inserir o dictionary como array
/// os outros valores estão já estão sendo inseridos
 public void InserirCfgMonitoramento(string nomeBD, string colecaoCfg, CfgMonitoramento cfgMonitoramento)
        {
            // Recupera coleção.
            MongoCollection<BsonDocument> colecao = RecColecao1(nomeBD,colecaoCfg);
            if (colecao != null)
            {
                // Seleciona configuração.
                IMongoQuery selecao = Query.EQ("Estacao", cfgMonitoramento.Estacao);
                MongoCursor cursor = colecao.FindAs(typeof(BsonDocument), selecao);
                // Define nome da estação.
                BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument("Estacao", cfgMonitoramento.Estacao);

                // Dados processo
                if (cfgMonitoramento.Processos != null && cfgMonitoramento.Processos.Count > 0 )
                {
                    List<General.Message.AgentQTS.Processo> processo = new List<General.Message.AgentQTS.Processo>();
                    List<BsonDocument> processosBD = new List<BsonDocument>();
                    BsonDocument docProcessos;
                    foreach (General.Message.AgentQTS.Processo proc in processo)
                    {
                        docProcessos = new BsonDocument("NomeProcesso", proc.NomeProcesso);


                        BsonArray variaveis = new BsonArray();
                        if (variaveis != null && variaveis.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, float> variavel in proc.Variaveis)
                                variaveis.Add(Convert.ToString(variavel.Key));
                        }

                        docProcessos.Add("Variaveis",new BsonArray(variaveis));
                        docProcessos.Add("TmoMonProcesso", cfgMonitoramento.TmoMonProcessos);
                        docProcessos.Add("UltimoMonProcessos", DateTime.Now);
                        processosBD.Add(docProcessos);
                    }
                    doc.Add("Processo", new BsonArray(processosBD));
                }
                doc.Add("Habilitado", cfgMonitoramento.Habilitado);
                colecao.Insert(doc);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Coleção {0} não encontrada!", colecaoCfg));


        }
```

Comment: Olá, teve a oportunidade de verificar a resposta? [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela ajuda, estou usando .net 3.5 então tive que criar o BsonDocument manualmente, não consegui de outra maneira.Mas consegui resolver meu problema

Comment: Adicione então essas informações na pergunta e escreva uma resposta para indicar como foi resolvido e marque a própria resposta como aceita. Assim outras pessoas com o mesmo problema poderão encontrar a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Ao usar o C# driver do MongoDB não é necessário criar o BsonDocument manualmente. Neste seu caso, seria possível fazer diretamente

```
colecao.InsertOneAsync(processo);
```

Para o dicionário ser inserido corretamente, pode ser necessário decorar a propriedade com `[BsonExtraElements]`.

```
public class Processo
{
    public string NomeProcesso;

    [BsonExtraElements]
    public Dictionary<string, float> Variaveis;

    public int QtdProcessadores;

(...)
```